# How to write a Java application who doesn't get the focus?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, javafx

Is it possible to write a Java application (Swing / JavaFX) who doesn't get the focus when launched? So that the application who had the focus before keeps it's focus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, sure. First if you create Window (not frame or JFrame) it does not get focus by default.
Second, just call f.setFocusableWindowState(false); on your frame and get the same behavior.